# How to judge one div is previous or next to another div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 div with corresponding id's in a sequence with the following ids (divele1, divele2, divele3, divele4, divele5). Now I have two div ids with with and Now I compare whether one div is previous or net element of another div.

ex: I have divele3 and divele5. Now I want to compare divele5 is previous or next element to divele3.

Any suggestions on the same

Comment: you can use index to compare if it comes before or after

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the `div` elements are children of the same container, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="divele1">devele1</div>
    <div id="divele2">devele2</div>
    <div id="divele3">devele3</div>
    <div id="divele4">devele4</div>
    <div id="divele5">devele5</div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply use `index()` to compare ordinal positions. For example:

```
var $div5 = $('#divele5');
var $div3 = $('#divele3');

if ($div3.index() < $div5.index()) {
    console.log('3 is before 5');
} else {
    console.log('5 is before 3');
}
```

If the `#diveleX` divs are not siblings at the same level of the DOM then you would need to give all of them a common class name and then use that in the `index()` method, like this:

```
<div id="divele1" class="divele" />
```

```js
$('#divele1').index('.divele');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `~` CSS `selector` select a *Sibling* that come next, so if you can select something like `#diveleX ~ #diveleY` means that *Y* is **next** to *X* otherwise come **before**.

Example:

```js
if ( document.querySelector( '#divele3 ~ #divele5' ) ) {
  console.log("divele5 is next to divele3");    // Print this
}
else {
  console.log("divele5 is before to divele 3");
}

if ( document.querySelector( '#divele4 ~ #divele3' ) ) {
  console.log("divele3 is next to divele4");
}
else {
  console.log("divele3 is before to divele4");    // Print this
}
```

```css
#test > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <div id="divele1">1</div>
    <div id="divele2">2</div>
    <div id="divele3">3</div>
    <div id="divele4">4</div>
    <div id="divele5">5</div>
</div>
```